# Are these characters safe to use in HTML, Postgres, and Bash?

Tags: regex, postgresql, unicode, multilingual

I have a project where I'm trying to enable other, possibly hostile, coders to label, in lowercase various properties that will be displayed in differing contexts, including embed in HTML, saved and manipulated in Postgres, used as attribute labels in JavaScript, and manipulated in the shell (say, saving a data file as продажи.zip) as well as various data analysis tools like graph-tool, etc.

I've worked on multilingual projects before, but they were either smaller customers that didn't need to especially worry about sophisticated attacks or they were projects that I came to *after* the multilingual aspect was in place, so I wasn't the one responsible for verifying security.

I'm pretty sure these should be safe, but I don't know if there are gotchas I need to look out for, like, say, a special [TAB] or [QUOTE] character in the Chinese character set that might escape my escaping.

Am I ok with these in my regex filter?

```
dash       = '-'
english    = 'a-z'
italian    = ''
russain    = 'а-я'
ukrainian  = 'ґї'
german     = 'äöüß'
spanish    = 'ñ'
french     = 'çéâêîôûàèùëï'
portuguese = 'ãõ'
polish     = 'ąćęłńóśźż'
turkish    = 'ğışç'
dutch      = 'áíúýÿìò'
swedish    = 'å'
danish     = 'æø'
norwegian  = ''
estonian   = ''
romainian  = 'șî'
greek      = 'α-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ'
chinese    = '([\p{Han}]+)'
japanese   = '([\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]+)'
korean     = '([\p{Hangul}]+)'
```

Comment: I've never had problems with Unicode in PostgreSQL. Problem with Bash and HTML is that they depend on what encoding is set on the terminal and the browser.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use appropriate identifier quoting/escaping for each lanugage? If you're outputting an identifier as a PostgreSQL identifier double any double quotes, so that `john "bobby" smith` becomes `"john ""bobby"" smith"`. If you're outputting a SQL literal, double single quotes. If you're outputting a string for the shell, backslash-escape shell metacharacters. etc. Rather than assuming your identifiers are trusted and free of metacharacters in the DB, assume they're untrusted and rigorously escape/quote on input and output.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yeah, I'm just not sure if there are edge cases I'm not taking into account. For example, it may be that the default character encoding for bash might not support some aspect of unicode which would allow a multibyte character to unescape the string being named, so I wanted to check if there was a known problem. So for example, john smith \ rm -rf may properly be escaped to "john smith \\ rm -rf" but "john 火災 rm -rf" might be misrepresented in the default bash character encoding and may inadvertently allow the execution of the command.

Comment: Basically, I don't know what I don't know when it comes to multilingual characters and when they are dangerous. I'm just vaguely aware that there might be gotchas that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: If you use the *appropriate escape mechanism* (existing function for this purpose) for the context in question (HTML, SQL, shell), then you're good. The last thing you should do is try to restrict characters based on some whitelist, especially if that spans several unrelated contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to text encodings with a 7-bit ASCII compatible subset, you're reasonably safe treating anything above `0x7f` (`U+007f`) as "safe" when interacting with most saneish programming languages and tools. If you use perl6 you're out of luck ;)

You should avoid supporting or take special care with input or output of text using the text encoding [Shift-JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS), where the `¥` symbol is at `0x5c` where `\` would usually reside. This offers opportunities for nefarious trickery by exploiting encoding conversions.

Avoid or take extra care with other non-ascii-compatible encodings too. EBDIC is one, but you're unlikely to ever meet it in the wild. UTF-16 and UTF-32 obviously, but if you misprocess them the results are glaringly obvious.

Reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Personally I think your approach is backwards. You should define input and output functions to escape and unescape strings according to the lexical syntaxes of each target tool or language, rather than trying to prohibit any possible metacharacter. But then I don't know your situation, and maybe it's just impractical for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your actual issue is. If you correctly convert your text to the target format, then you don't care what the text could possibly be. This will ensure both proper conversion AND security.

For instance:

- If your text is to be included in HTML, it should be escaped using appropriate HTML quoting functions.

  Example:

  **Wrong**

  ```
  // XXX DON'T DO THIS XXX
  echo "<span>".$variable."</span>"
  ```

  Right:

  ```
  // Actual encoding function varies based your environment
  echo "<span>".htmlspecialchars($variable)."</span>"
  ```

  Yes, this will also handle properly the case of text containing `&` or `<`.
- If your text is to be used in an SQL query, you should use parameterised queries.

  Example:

  **Wrong**

  ```
  // XXX DON'T DO THIS XXX
  perform_sql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE thing=".$variable")
  ```

  Right

  ```
  // Actual syntax and function will vary
  perform_sql_query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE thing=?", [$variable]);
  ```
- If you text is to be included in JSON, just use appropriate JSON-encoding functions.

  Example:

  **Wrong**

  ```
  // XXX DON'T DO THIS XXX
  echo '{"this":"'.$variable.'"}'
  ```

  Right

  ```
  // actual syntax and function may vary
  echo json_encode({this: $variable});
  ```

The shell is a bit more tricky, and it's often a pain to deal with non-ASCII characters in many environments (e.g. FTP or doing an `scp` between different environments). So don't use explicit names for files, use identifiers (numeric id, uuid, hash...) and store the mapping to the actual name somewhere else (in a database).

Comment: Perfect thank you @jcaron. Of course I knew the bit about SQL sanitization, but I'd never dealt with frontend sanitization before because I've usually been more of a backend dev (machine learning).

Comment: Note that sanitisation is not the same as escaping or using parameterised queries. Sanitisation involves making sure your data is what you expect it to be. Escaping or using parameterised queries is all about not caring what the data could possibly be.